# Listening For Beacons When App is Not Running

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to listen for iBeacons when my app is not running (the user quit the app and it is not running in the background).

I have specified the Bluetooth LE Background Mode and can listen for and receive sightings when the app is active and in the background. However, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to implement the same functionality for when my app is not running.

I've been reading the [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) guide and trying to implement CBCentralManagerDelegate - if that is the correct solution for this scenario. I don't understand where I implement the `CBCentralManagerDelegate`. Do I implement it in the `AppDelegate` or in the view controller that handles beacon sightings? Do I have to declare a `CBCentralManager`? What do I do in `centralManagerDidUpdateState:`?

I don't care about restoring or preserving state, I just want my application to receive beacon sightings when it is not running.

I have added the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and am asking for permission for the location.

Let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple treats iBeacon support differently than other BLE services.

It considers iBeacons monitoring to be a Location Manager service.

You want to add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key to your app's info.plist.

At startup, you want to check the location manager's authorization status, and if it's not `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways` then you want to request it. That code looks like this:

```
CLAuthorizationStatus status =[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (status != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways
  && [self.theLocManager respondsToSelector: 
    @selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
  {
    [self.theLocManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
  }
```

### EDIT:

In your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, you need to check the options for the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`.

To quote the relevant part of the CLLocationManager Class Reference:

> If a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not
>   running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in
>   the background so that it can process the event. In this case, the
>   options dictionary passed to the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your app delegate
>   contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate
>   that your app was launched because of a location-related event. During
>   the relaunch process, you must recreate your location manager object
>   and assign a delegate capable of handling region-related events. After
>   you do that, the system delivers the region notification for which
>   your app was launched. All of the regions you configured previously
>   are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location
>   manager objects you create.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I am doing all of that. What do I need to add that will tell me when the app wakes up?

Comment: On launch you need to create an instance of the location manager and set yourself up as it's delegate. Once you've done all that, and also started monitoring one or more beacon regions, you should get launched and receive location manager `didEnterRegion` messages.

Comment: I just edited my answer to document another step you will need to take.